# How do I fix the error on erased SceneDeleate related with UIKit?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, uikit, uiscenedelegate

At first, Xcode always been terminated with the error related with EnvironmentObject. To utilize EnvironmentObject on Xcode, I created SceneDelegate.swift since my project didn't contain it. Then it works, but another error occurs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcjF9.png)

To avoid this error, I deleted not only SceneDelegate.swift but also the properties on info.plist. Anyway EnvironmentObject is still working, but the error is shown on the screenshot still appears. Even the error is still showing on the log, the project is working properly as my expectation. Does anyone know any solution to fix this error? This is pretty weird the error still showing even I deleted SceneDelegate file.

Comment: The error clearly states that you're trying to use UIKit in a project that supports macOS. UIKit is for iOS/iPadOS, AppKit is for macOS, WatchKit is for watchOS, and SwiftUI can be used everywhere.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and enter the error message as text, not image.